# Correlation coefficient question regarding coin tosses

Tags: probability

So a coin is tossed 10 times in this question.

$X=$ number of heads in the first 5 tosses

$Y=$ number of heads in total

$T=$ number of tails in the first 5 tosses

I am asked to calculate the correlation coefficient of both $X$ and $Y$ and also $T$ and $Y$. It asks me whether the answers make any sense.

So I was able to work out the correlation coefficient of $X$ and $Y$ easily and it is $\frac {1}{\sqrt2}$. Although I am not sure how to work out the correlation coefficient of $T$ and $Y$? I think I am having a mind block!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $T=5-X$. So, you are really asked to find the correlation coefficient between $5-X$ and $Y$.

You can probably write this in terms of the correlation coefficient between $X$ and $Y$!